# centering links in a navigation bar

Tags: css

I have a navigation bar with 8 links in it.  I would like the set of links centered within the bar but I just can't seem to do it.  With the following css the link all the way on the left is indented  within the bar, but the last link comes up to the very end of the bar.  Is there some way to get the bar's width to expand so that the links are centered within it?  Thanks.

HTML:

```
 <div class="table">
 <ul id="navbar">
 <li><a href="etc....."ETC</a></li>
 <li...
 <li....
 <li...
 .
 .
 .
 .
 </ul>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
 table {display:table;margin:0 auto;
 }
 #navbar {
min-height: 50px;
border: thin groove #000;
background-repeat: repeat;
background-image: url(Images/navbackground.jpg);
margin-top: 0px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: auto;
  }
 #navbar li {
font-size: 1em;
padding-right: 0px;
list-style-image: none;
list-style-type: none;
float: left;
display: inline;

 }
 #navbar  li a {
display: block;
text-decoration: none; /* space between links */
color: #FFF;
width: auto;
font-weight: bold;
line-height: 1em;
background-color: #06F;
padding: 5px;
border: 1px solid #000;
font-size: .8em;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-right: 5px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
margin-left: 5px;
 }
```

Comment: Throw this in a jsfiddle so we can see what you have. If I understand the goal - you'll need to center the `ul` itself inside of a larger parent element.

Comment: use `display-inline` but not `float`

Comment: @JFK Why not float? `inline` does the same but they both have caveats that are a pain to deal with.

Comment: I need the float so the links line up from left to right in the navbar.

Comment: @ASKER, btw, text-decoration: none; /* space between links */ is more about the underline of the links, not the space between them :)

Comment: with all the arguments anyone can bring up to the table, this http://jsfiddle.net/dHLLe/ how to achieve what you are asking for using `display:inline` instead of `float` and without setting a specific `width` to the `ul` element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

define a width and margin on your div of:

```
div {
    margin: 0 auto;/*0 here sets top and bottom margin to 0 and auto centers the UL*/
    width: 906px;/*Can be whatever you desire*/
}
```

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S9fF5/2/) for a demo.

EDIT 1: Remove your `display: table` style on your `div`

EDIT 2: I suppose I should also mention adding a `ul:after` to your CSS too

```
ul:after
{
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear:both;
}
```

EDIT 3: Welcome to the [CSS Box Model](http://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/)
Long story short: By default, when you define a width (`width: 100px;`), `margin` and `padding` are EXTRA.  E.g. a DIV with 100px width and padding left and right of 30px takes up 160px.

E.g.

```
div
{
    width: 100px;
    padding: 0 30px;
}
```

A way to change this behavior is by using:

```
div
{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 0 30px;
}
```

By using `box-sizing: box-model` the "width" of the DIV effectively becomes (in this example) 40px (100px - 30px - 30px = 40px).

**SO**
I created a new [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S9fF5/3/) for you, in which I added:

```
li:not(:first-child)
{
    margin-left: 30px;
}
```

AND changed the DIV's width to 360 (since there are two 30px margins applied).

HAPPY CODING!

P.S.
You should totally accept my answer by clicking on the checkmark to the left of my answer ;)

Comment: doesn't work.  Links still not centered in navbar.  I made width 960 so now the left hand link is slightly indented, and the right hand one is way indented from the end of the navbar.  There is no automatic centering.

Comment: It is because the DIV is displayed as a table.

Comment: taking out the table div does not change anything.   Not sure why I put it in in the first place but, again, taking it out changes nothing.

Comment: @ddenhartog It is not being displayed as a table. the div's class is "table". Read up on Classes.

Comment: @Dozer, I glanced at the first line in the CSS and saw `display: table` , then glanced at the element and saw `table`, which I mistook for `.table`.  My answer/JSFiddle still applies/works :)

Comment: Your answer works great right now, but in the CSS, it was `table`, and not `.table` like it should have been. Unless it was a `table`, and not a `class`, it would need to be `table` and not `.table`.

Comment: Yeah, I just figured he wouldn't define `display: table` on `table`, but rather the copy&paste just didn't include the preceding `.`

Comment: weird thing is if I add a padding-right to #navbar li of 30 px or more, the bar expands and centers the links.  Anything less than 30 they're still not centered!

Comment: Please see "EDIT 3" in my answer and also check out the new [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S9fF5/3/) I created for you.